# How to encode TO a 4 digits number or nummerical string in JAVA?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, encode, des

I am relatively new to java and i've been breaking my head the last few days in order to finish a task, and everything went good until this last "quest".

More Specific:

I want to create an encrypted/encoded 4 digits number out of 3 string fields. You can imagine it as trying to produce a 4 digit CVV number like in the credit cards, with the help of(in terms of depending from) the card number, the exp. date and the service code. To achive this, i first encrypted the card number using DES with random key, then encrypted(DES) the exp date using the encrypted card number as a key, and as last step, i encrypted(DES) service code using the encrypted exp date as a key. So far, so good, i can retrieve in every step the infoarmations needed. The problem is that the encrypted service code, which will be my final output, shall have the length 4 and shall contains only digits. After two days of researching in the net, after trying several attempts, like:

- **hashing** : problem was there was no decode back from hash value to encrypted service code
- **Base64 Transformation** : couldn't achieve length and only digits
- **padding** : would loose vital information
- **further encryption** : couldn't find an algorithm producing such a short (in terms of length) key.

Is there any other solution?

Here is the last 2 steps of the algorithm, just to get you an idea of how it is running.

desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey_2);

```
        // Sensitive information - message to be encrypted
        byte[] date_of_exp = "032019".getBytes(); // Date of Expiration in form MMYYYY

        //System.out.println("Card Number : " + card_number); // Print original message

        // Encrypt the text
       byte[] date_of_expEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(date_of_exp);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Date of Expiration Encrypted : " + date_of_expEncrypted); // Print the encrypted message
        System.out.println("");

        // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey_2);

        String date_of_expEncrypted_;
        date_of_expEncrypted_ = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(date_of_expEncrypted); 
        // SecretKey card_numberEncrypted_key;
        // card_numberEncrypted_key = stringToSecretKey (card_numberEncrypted_, "DES");
        SecretKey date_of_expEncrypted_key;
        date_of_expEncrypted_key = new SecretKeySpec(date_of_expEncrypted, 0, 8, "DES");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Date of expiration as secret key :" + date_of_expEncrypted_key);
        System.out.println("");

        // Decrypt the text
        byte[] date_of_expDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(date_of_expEncrypted);

        System.out.println("Original Date of Expiration (decrypted) : " + new String(date_of_expDecrypted)); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Further to Step 3"); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");




    SecretKey myDesKey_3 = date_of_expEncrypted_key;

    //Cipher desCipher_2; // New Cipher for iteration 2

        // Create the cipher 
        //desCipher_2 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey_3);

        // Sensitive information - message to be encrypted
        byte[] service_code = "318".getBytes(); 

       // Encrypt the text
       byte[] service_codeEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(service_code);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Service Code Encrypted : " + service_codeEncrypted); // Print the encrypted message
        System.out.println("");
        // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey_3);

        // Decrypt the text
        byte[] service_codeDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(service_codeEncrypted);

        System.out.println("Service Code decrypted : " + new String(service_codeDecrypted)); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Finish!!!"); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); // Print the decrypted Text
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");


        //Integer bigInt = new Integer("Bwwhw34".getBytes());
        // int service_codeEncrypted_hashed = service_codeEncrypted.hashCode();
        // System.out.println("hash code for Service Code Encrypted : " + service_codeEncrypted_hashed);
        // int service_codeEncrypted_hashed_2 = service_codeEncrypted_hashed.hashCode();

        // byte[] service_code__ = service_codeEncrypted.getBytes(); 
        //  System.out.println("hash code for Service Code Encrypted and baseD  : " + service_code__);



    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(BadPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

Output "Service Code Encrypted" would be in form [B@84abc9, wich is useless for my purposes.

Thanx in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Your task is fundamentally impossible: there are infinitely many character strings but only 10000 4-digit numbers.

Comment: Tahnk you for the response. I was almost certain about it, just wanted to be 100% sure. Time to search for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to create an encrypted/encoded 4 digits number out of 3 string fields."

Your only choice is a hash, otherwise you'll need Harry Potter to help you out. Or did you expect that you can transform 4 digits back into any 3 possible Strings? I'm afraid that kind of compression doesn't exist.

As for your "[B@84abc9". That's the default toString() for a byte array. You'll want to turn it into hexadecimal or Base64 before displaying it.

Comment: i have already created the string out of the 3 string fields and at the moment, security is not an option since i am covered from the encryption in the previous steps. The actual question is how to encode a string to a 4 digits number and how to recover it afterwards. Hash could have been ideal, if there was a "dehash" function...

Comment: @kiko77 You're asking for impossible things. There is no way you can get your original Strings back from 4 digits. Therefore the only way would be to either allow for more than 4 digits, or use a hash and cut it down to 4 chars (or digits).

Comment: I thought it was near to impossible, but just wanted to be sure. Hash works only one way (as far as i know) and therefore does not really help me.

Comment: @kiko77 Yes, and that's why a hash can be used to convert a large amount of data into a small piece. Because it loses information. Same doesn't apply for compression (or encryption, if you're still on about that).

Comment: It was almost clear that it was impossible. Thank you for your reply. I wish i have asked it earlier so i could save many workhours of trying and searching and concetrate to a possible new approach!